# Disable close button on DOS program in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, command-line, batch-file

At my company we have stores that run some old DOS software.

Before Windows 7 you could run these programs in full-screen and now you cannot.

I know there are work-arounds to get in full-screen (e.g. DOSBox, rolling back video drivers). However both of these solutions have been shown to cause problems.

As an alternative we we want to disable the close button on the command prompt window which loads this DOS program.

Reason being, the program has it's own method of closing which worked well with full-screen but now without it users are clicking the close button and a close like this messes with our data.

How can I disable the close button.

Any help is appreciated, thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could re-invent the wheel and create your own wrapper to launch your program, using something like AutoIt, or your favorite programming language.

Or you could use [Uwe Sieber's ConsoleNoClose](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/files/consolenoclose.zip) program to do just that: disable the Close (X) button on a command prompt window. When you launch the program it stays resident and disables the button on any open command prompt as it gets the focus.

Tested on Windows 7 Professional 32-bit.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

I have used Uwe Sieber's 'Close Window' from his Windows Tools section.
From Windows Tools Page - [CloseWindow V0.1 - closing windows](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/misc_tools_e.html)
To download direct -
[Uwe Sieber's ConsoleNoClose](http://www.uwe-sieber.de/files/consolenoclose.zip)
It works quite well! Just start it with the perameter "/1" in the batch file.

Comment: This tool was suggested in the first answer, over a year ago.